# Apache Lucene query with specific rule

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, solr, lucene, search-engine

I have multiple documents in Lucene index
and I want to make an query depend on specific rule , in other words I want to make a query for the whole documents and except some documents from the search , the documents that I want to exclude contains a specific value of specific TextField.

for example.

```
name: John
bio: bla bla bla 
age: 25
```

I want to make a query that should search in all documents that they don't have age field, and if they have age field I want to search in the document but with specific rule for example the age should be more 30

Answer (score 0):

The following query should help you achieve that. It will retrieve either documents that don't have the `age` field or for those that have it, only the documents where `age > 30`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1, 
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "age"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "age": {
              "gt": 30
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The equivalent [Lucene query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) would be:

```
NOT(_exists_:age) OR age:{30 TO *}
```

Comment: But we don't have ability to make query using JSON in Apache Lucene as far as I know

Comment: Just curious, why did you tag your question with elasticsearch? I've updated my answer with the equivalent Lucene query

Comment: Because Elastic search is a Lucene-based engine, so I expected experts in elastic search can help with it.

Comment: Does my update answer your question then?

Comment: and another question also , how this Lucene query can be used in Lucene SDK ?

Comment: You can use the [Lucene SDK](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_7_0/core/index.html) with `QueryParser.parse()` to build a query from that query string above